# after login with ssh i doesn't get sysinfo

Tags: 18.04, ssh, login, system, motd

experts,
i'm using ubuntu 18.04 LTS headless server. After login over ssh i get the following message:

```
> Authenticating with public key "rsa-key-blablabla" 
> Last login: Wed Aug 12 10:16:01 2020 from xx.xx.xx.xxx
```

there is the `landscape-sysinfo` missing and i don't now why. With the command `landscape-sysinfo`
the system display the information,but i wanted the information after login. the package `landscape-common` is allready included in Ubuntu 18.04. I don't know where is the problem ?And i have nothing edit in folder `/etc/update-motd.d` . hope somebody can help me.

kind regard
blackbeard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have root access (sudo) ? Can you install with ?

```
sudo apt install landscape-common
```

Edit : I may have understood your problem ? You want to run this command at every login ?

If so, just edit your .bashrc

```
nano ~/.bashrc
#add line to bottom of .bashrc
landscape-sysinfo
```

Comment: thanks the last advice works, now i wanted to see the update/ upgrade information about the system, what should i must add in bashrc ?